# how to load angularjs and my models at the correct time

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling to find a way to get angular and my code to play nicely and since angular is awesome i know it must be my problem.
Some of my models have static data only but most have either only dynamic data that i pull in from rest services or a combination of static/rest data.
many of the examples i see here and in the docs just deal with a small static json set of data.

My problem when i put the angular script call in the html it tries to load and execute before my models are loaded and ready to go. there has to be a way to coordinate that loading time.

So i have tried to devise ways to make sure my model js scripts are all loaded and then finally call for the angular script in a getScript call.

Also i wrote a custom filter and i want that to be added to my module. when i add the module name to the ng-app tag and i try to lazy load the angular script via getScript it errors and says it doesn't recognize my module name.
If i remove the module name from ng-app and then try to initialize my filter module it does lazy load angular.js but then it says my filter method is invalid because (i guess) it is not registered with the model.

I'm sure i'm missing some key piece of information somewhere. Angular has to be smart enough to load and then realize that my models will take a few moments to arrive. Not just run through my html and bark at the first ng-controller tag because the model isn't loaded or the service call to fill the model is not done yet.

Right now if i put a tag on my html like so:

```
<html class="no-js" ng-app="yourApp">
```

I get an error when i call getScript on angular.js that says

> angular.js failed to load: Error: No module: yourApp

Please help. thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you load angularjs not during page load, but via an ajax call? If you do that you will need to do a [manual bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

Here is an example I'm using with [`require.js`](http://requirejs.org/), but with jquery's `$.getScript()`, it will be similar:

```
require(['angular', 'jquery', 'app/app-config'], function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

In your case it will be something like:

```
$.getScript("http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.4/angular.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Just make sure all javascript files with controllers, directives, ... are loaded too.

Comment: so in that example i would not be using the ng-app="myApp" tag? I was able to move my angular.js call into a script tag in the html so i have that now. i dont need getScript anymore. But anytime i put the name of my module in the ng-app tag i get an error about the module not be found. finally i added a jquery .ready script that initialized my module. i think it is available now

Comment: My next problem is that when my custom filter tries to run i get this annoying message about $apply already in progress. I am not calling apply anywhere. And my filter works fine with static data http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/gTUZd/16/

Comment: I would really like to use this custom filter because it seems like the right thing to do. but its too painful. I think i could accomplish the same thing with an ng-change event that then runs my filter logic and modifies the model.

Comment: I guess i should create a new question as this has morphed slightly

Comment: sure don't like polluting my html page with a jquery.ready call just to recognize this filter